# How can I get the path of all files with specific extension

Tags: file, go, directory

I tried to act like a question using the `filepath.Wark` function.

```
var paths []string
err := os.Chdir("C:\\")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
err = filepath.Walk(".", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if !info.IsDir() {
        matched, err := filepath.Match(extension /*"*.reg"*/, info.Name())
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if matched {
            paths = append(paths, path)
        }
    }
    return nil
})
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

41 reg files were found this way, but using the everything program, 103 reg files were found.

I want to have 103 results. First of all, I checked that reg file exists not only in Program Files but also in the Users folder, but not found in go.

I ran admin permission.

Comment: Post your actual code.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I updated the source code fixes.

Comment: This could be a permission issue

Comment: @diyoda_ i ran admin permission. edit my contents...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [filepath.Ext](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Ext) to find the extension of the file, lowercase it and test equality with `.reg`. That would be a better way for just extensions.

Another reason could be that you might not have permissions to browse other users' directory in Users directory. Try running the program as administrator.